# jQuery find form element by attributes name and value?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to check a radio button but all I have as a ref to the element is the name attribute and the elements value.

I need some way to check the correct radio where name="accounts\['+i+'\]\[account_status\]\[selected\]" and value="current" in "#form1".

I have the code below but it checks the last radio button.

```
$('#form1 input[name="accounts\\['+i+'\\]\\[account_status\\]\\[selected\\]"]').attr('checked', true);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You seem to have left out the `value` part.  Because of that, it's trying to check all of them regardless of value.  Since only one radiobutton in a group can be checked at a time, only the last is checked in the end.

Add the value on the end.

```
input[name='something'][value='something']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KsJCP/

Answer (score 1):

A much better way to see this selection working is shown below:

```
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="three">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="four">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="five">
<input type="radio" name="some[thing]" value="six">

alert('1'); // All are unchecked
$("input[value='four'][name='some\\[thing\\]']").attr("checked",true);
alert('2'); // 4th is checked
$("input[value='four'][name='some\\[thing\\]']").attr("checked",false);
alert('3'); // 4th is unchecked
```